# How to implement complex animation?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I've been surfing the spinning wheel top arrow animation for android animation, and all what I found was the spinning wheel (https://github.com/adef145/SpinningWheelAndroid) but top arrow is a stick.

For example, I want top arrow animation which is in unity application "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.treebit.decisionroulette", so how I can animate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest Lottie for you, https://lottiefiles.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to animate views in android without using external libraries. One way is ObjectAnimator. This will spin an ImageView endlessly:

```
ImageView imageView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(500);
    objectAnimator.start();
```

Stop it with:

```
if(objectAnimator != null && objectAnimator.isStarted()) {
            objectAnimator.end();
            objectAnimator.cancel();
        }
```

Or even easier (but untested):

```
imageView.animate().rotationBy(360f).start();
```

Edit: Checkout AnimatorListener to start the animation of the arrow once the wheel has finished turning for X degrees.

```
new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: No, I already implemented rotate animation but that couldn't fit in my requirements. top arrow animation is happen when part section start. Please check again application or see this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjih3IH52dE